# momentJs with class not work correctly django

Tags: javascript, python, django

hi i have a difficulty with moment.js first entry it good but after i have invalid date .

I call my data in front with {{....}} :

```
{% for lastRequest in listLastRequeteClient %}
<!-- en attente -->
    <li class="collection-item">
        <span class="title">{{ lastRequest.categoryName }}</span>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s5 ultra-small leftalign "style="padding-left: 0px">
                {{ lastRequest.nameRequest }}
            </div>
            <div class="col s3 ultra-small center-align">
                <span class="countDateTime">{{ lastRequest.dateRequest }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col s4 ultra-small ">
                {% if lastRequest.isWaitingWorking == True %}
                    <span class="new badge orange" data-badge-caption="En attente"></span>
                {% elif lastRequest.isWaitingWorking == True %}
                    <span class="new badge blue" data-badge-caption="En cours"></span>
                {% elif lastRequest.isFinish == True %}
                    <span class="new badge" data-badge-caption="Effectué"></span>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
% endfor %}
```

and my Javascript   :

```
function countDateEntry()
{
    $(".countDateTime").each(function()
    {

        // get it  Oct. 27, 2017, 2:27 p.m
        var dateEntry = $(this).text();
        console.log(dateEntry);


        // format it
        var delSpace = dateEntry.replace(/ /gi, "");
        var delVir = delSpace.replace(/,/gi, "");
        var delDoublePoint = delVir.replace(/:/gi, "");
        var FinishSerialize = delDoublePoint.replace(/\./gi, "");

        console.log(FinishSerialize);

        // test is date is valid
        console.log(moment(FinishSerialize, 'MMMDYYYYhma').isValid());

        var formatMomentDate = moment(FinishSerialize, 'MMMDYYYYhma').fromNow();
        console.log(formatMomentDate);
        //$(this).text(formatMomentDate);

    });
}
```

but show my console.log invalid date :

First entry it is ok after it is bad .

```
        Oct. 27, 2017, 2:27 p.m.
        Oct272017227pm
        true
        3 days ago
        Oct. 28, 2017, 8:39 p.m.
        Oct282017839pm
        false
        Invalid date
        Oct. 30, 2017, 6:28 p.m.
        Oct302017628pm
        false
        Invalid date
        Oct. 30, 2017, 6:29 p.m.
        Oct302017629pm
        false
        Invalid date
```

An idea ??
I'm french sorry for my bad English .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format `MMMDYYYYhma` cannot be parsed unambiguously. Instead use a standard date format that both django and moment.js will handle.

Both support [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and [RFC 2822/5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html#section-3.3) formats with no extra configuration.

ISO 8601 django:

```
{{ lastRequest.dateRequest|date:"c" }}
```

RFC 5322 django:

```
{{ lastRequest.dateRequest|date:"r" }}
```

Moment will be able to parse both these formats

```js
var ISO_date = "2017-10-06T05:06:07"
var RFC_date = "06 Oct 2017 21:22:23 z"
console.log("ISO 8601:", ISO_date, " => ", moment(ISO_date))
console.log("RFC 5322/2822:", RFC_date, " => ", moment(RFC_date))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seems that moment.js interprets `h` as either 24 hours or 12 hour clock, for some reason (it seem inconsistent with what's described in the docs). The parsing fails since `83:09` is not a valid time. For your cases, it seems that changing the format string to `MMMDYYYYhmma` (one more `m`) works. But there could be other cases that break.

Comment: Thx guys you are the best :) RFC 5322 django valid for me